# Prevent multiple form submits. Is there a simple solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I do not know how to prevent multiple form submits in ajax. What I have seen on the Web by now are either non working solutions or real behemoths (tons of curvy code for such a microscopic task. what for?). What I have now is this code:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
  $('#form').submit(function(e){
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray(),
    formURL = $(this).attr('action');
    $.ajax({
        url:formURL,
        type:'POST',
        data:postData,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){

        },
        error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

I wish there was a one-stroke elegant solution, like some mysterious property or a function call.

Comment: you could disable #btn on click and re-enable on ajax end, its what I usually do

Comment: The mysterious: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do is disable submit on click to prevent more hits, and re-enable it when ajax is done:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
  $(this).prop('disabled', true)  // disable submit to prevent multiple sends
  $('#form').submit(function(e){
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray(),
    formURL = $(this).attr('action');
    $.ajax({
        url:formURL,
        type:'POST',
        data:postData,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){

        },
        error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

        },
        always:function(){ // it its a success or a fail, we want to re-enable it
            $(this).prop('disabled', false) 
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
 $('#btn').click(function(){
  $(this).prop("disabled",true);
  $('#form').submit(function(e){
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray(),
    formURL = $(this).attr('action');
    $.ajax({
        url:formURL,
        type:'POST',
        data:postData,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
              $('#btn').prop("disabled",false);
        },
        error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
              //handle error
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: what happens if there is an error on form since you did not enable the button on error?

Comment: That is up to you to handle the way you want! You can enable the button again for instance.

Comment: you should disable the button on the submit not on the success.. otherwise double clicks will still register twice etc.

Comment: @CᴴᵁᴮᴮʸNᴵᴺᴶᴬ the button is disabled on `#btn` click, it is renabled on success!

Comment: @callback ahh yes sorry my mistake did not see your initial `prop`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#form').submit(function(e){
$('#btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
var postData = $(this).serializeArray(),
formURL = $(this).attr('action');
$.ajax({
    url:formURL,
    type:'POST',
    data:postData,
    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){

    },
    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

    },
    complete: function() {
        $('#btn').removeAttr('disabled');
    }

});

e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Is there a difference between `complete` and `always` property in the context of this task?

Comment: not sure but imho you should go for complete. It is what you got from jquery website :

A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed). The function gets passed two arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object and a string categorizing the status of the request ("success", "notmodified", "nocontent", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror")

Comment: you welcome! My bad  about "always" since "complete" tend to be deprecated

An alternative construct to the complete callback option, the .always() method replaces the deprecated .complete() method.